# Checking the value of a key in a dictionary within a list?

Tags: python, dictionary

So I haven't exactly used Python in a while and I'm rusty - I'm working on a personal project and the API I'm using returns a list of dictionaries that represent a song's data.  What I'm trying to do is essentially trim down the returned list of songs to ONLY those with a rating of 5 (and to delete all others from the list). I have some code below that doesn't seem to be working.  It doesn't seem to actually remove anything, and prints out the entire list of songs (which in my case gets pretty large, as it is around 11,000 songs or so).

As a bit of help, I'll also post an example of what the API returns (for one song):

```
{
   'comment':'',
   'rating':'0',
   'albumArtRef':[
     {
       'url': 'http://lh6.ggpht.com/...'
     }
   ],
   'artistId':[
     'Aod62yyj3u3xsjtooghh2glwsdi'
   ],
   'composer':'',
   'year':2011,
   'creationTimestamp':'1330879409467830',
   'id':'5924d75a-931c-30ed-8790-f7fce8943c85',
   'album':'Heritage ',
   'totalDiscCount':0,
   'title':'Haxprocess',
   'recentTimestamp':'1372040508935000',
   'albumArtist':'',
   'trackNumber':6,
   'discNumber':0,
   'deleted':False,
   'storeId':'Txsffypukmmeg3iwl3w5a5s3vzy',
   'nid':'Txsffypukmmeg3iwl3w5a5s3vzy',
   'totalTrackCount':10,
   'estimatedSize':'17229205',
   'albumId':'Bdkf6ywxmrhflvtasnayxlkgpcm',
   'beatsPerMinute':0,
   'genre':'Progressive Metal',
   'playCount':7,
   'artistArtRef':[
     {
       'url': 'http://lh3.ggpht.com/...'
     }
   ],
   'kind':'sj#track',
   'artist':'Opeth',
   'lastModifiedTimestamp':'1330881158830924',
   'clientId':'+eGFGTbiyMktbPuvB5MfsA',
   'durationMillis':'418000'
 }
```

And my code is as follows:

```
library = api.get_all_songs()
    print("There are",len(library),"items in your music library")
    for track in library:
        if track['rating'] != 5:
            library.remove(track)
    print("You have",len(library),"favorite tracks!")
    return library
```

I added in the "favorite songs" amount (as well as the number of songs in the library) to test and see if my loop and if statement would remove anything, and it doesn't (as the numbers are the same before and after the loop) - I figure it has something to do with that, as the code works fine otherwise, it just doesn't prune the list.

If any extra code is needed, I'd be more than happy to provide it.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to delete items from a list you're looping over. It's a bit like sawing off a tree branch you're sitting on. :) See [strange result when removing item from a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/4014959) for details. However, you _can_ do it safely if you iterate backwards over the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a list comprehension to filter your list of dictionaries:

```
library = ...

good_songs = [ x for x in library if x['rating'] == '5' ]
```

Comment: Yup, was gonna suggest doing it this way as well. +1

Comment: Based on the example he gave, it looks like ratings are strings; the comparison should probably be `if x['rating'] == '5'`

Comment: Good catch! I saw all the integers and just assumed rating was an integer, too. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

The API is treating the rating as a string.

You are treating the rating as an integer. That's why no track is ever deleted.

Comment: I thought that as well on my first attempt, and used this code to check `if track['rating'] is 0: library.remove(track)` and it didn't actually filter anything either, so maybe they are treated as integers? the API documentation isn't 100% clear on this either